# Hide context menu in Edge that pops up after selecting text

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I select text in Microsoft Edge, a context menu sometimes pops up...

**How can I disable it?**

[image: mini menu example]

Answer (score 8):

You can change this in the settings.  Go to `edge://settings/appearance`

Then disable **"Show mini menu when selecting text"**

[image: Mini Menu Settings]